# Highcharts colorAxis - Hide or add dynamically

Tags: highcharts

I have a system set up where the user adds a chart and then selects the type they want. If I add the chart with the colorAxis in place, how do I hide it or remove it for those charts where I don't need it?

If I create the chart without the colorAxis, what is the proper way to add the colorAxis? I tried using the addAxis just like you would for any other axis, but there are problems. The remove function removed the colorAxis from the chart object, but not from the chart. It also resulted in an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can destroy colorAxis by remove legend.

```
chart.legend.destroy();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/h0rkf05t/

Comment: Thanks, but that will destroy the legend in all cases for all plots. I need to remove the colorAxis legend so that I can change the chart type dynamically and add/remove the colorAxis legend.